# Add CDATA to XML element with SimpleXML and WITHOUT dom_import_simplexml()

Tags: php, dom, simplexml

I have a deadline for this project (Monday). It worked great on the localhost, but when I uploaded it to our web server, I discovered that we do not have all of the DOM package enabled and I cannot use the function dom_import_simplexml(). My server admin is ignoring my requests, probably because of the short notice, and I cannot possibly rewrite the XML system into a database system that quickly.

This appears to be the only error I'm encountering. Please, if you have any alternative ideas, I'd love to hear them. I'm at a loss, because I can't find any other solution. All I have to do is create some XML elements and populate them with CDATA values, and I can't believe that this is not supported by SimpleXML!

Please, are there any alternatives you can think of? I'm open, because I don't know what I can do.

```
  // Add a <pages /> element
  $xml->addChild('pages');
  // Populate it with data 
  foreach($pages as $page){
   $new = $xml->pages->addChild('page');
   $new->addAttribute('pid', $page['pid']);
   $new->addAttribute('title', $page['title']);
   if(isset($page['ancestor']))
    $new->addAttribute('ancestor', $page['ancestor']);
   $node = dom_import_simplexml($new);
   $no = $node->ownerDocument;
   $node->appendChild($no->createCDATASection($page['content']));
  }
```

Those last three lines obviously won't work, and I don't know what else I can do with them!

Thank you so much for any help you can provide.

Comment: Is your problem with `dom_import_simplexml()`, or is the entire `DOMDocument` class not present? (What happens if you run `$doc = new DOMDocument;`)

Comment: I get a fatal error because the DOMDocument class does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

them not supporting this is baffling. You must hack the stream.

```
$xml->node = '<![CDATA[character data]]>'; 
echo preg_replace('/\]\]&gt;</', ']]><', preg_replace('/&lt;!\[CDATA/','<![CDATA',  $xml->asXML()));
```

This is problematic, perhaps those strings might show up in your cdata somewhere. A risk you'll have to take.

Sorry I couldn't help you with your deadline, but at least anyone annoyed with using DOM or unable to use it will have a solution of sorts.